# Javascript update razor variable using onclick element

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Is it possible to update a razor variable using onclick on a element?

**MVC VIEW:**

```
@{
    string iconNumber = "1";
}

<button type="submit" onclick="@iconNumber = '2'; alert('@iconNumber');"></button>
```

**Console error:**
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

*Thanks*

Comment: Is there any reason the variable needs to be a razor variable? You typically would not implement a workflow like this... what is your actual final goal? Do you want to send some value back to the server? Retrieve a server value and then manipulate it on the client?

Comment: I want to use that variable in my ajax.beginform, onbegin, so i can set which icon that should be hidden on start. I have three submit buttons for the same form. The button that is pressed (submitted) should be hidden. I can't just simply hide it in onclick because I'm using jquery validation and i don't want to hide it if the form doesn't end up in my oncomplete function. Wow, hope I don't confuse you too much now.

Comment: the error Invalid left-hand side in assignment because you trying to assign a value to a constant means '1'='2'

Comment: Do you know how to assign an id to the buttons? If not, let me know. You'll use those ids to display/hide the appropriate one useing jquery - not razor. Let me know if this makes sense. It might help if you could show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading this question the day after, one would think I was under the influence of drugs.

I came up with a better solution that only uses javascript variables:

**VIEW:**

```
<script>var iconNumber = 0;</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "",
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        OnBegin = "$('#iconElement' + iconNumber).attr('class', 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin');",
                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                    }))
    {
Html input here

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="IconElement1" onclick="iconNumber = 1;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="IconElement2" onclick="iconNumber = 2;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="IconElement3" onclick="iconNumber = 3;">

}
```

I can now disable the form after submit to prevent multiple requests. Because I don't start the spinner directly in onclick I don't have to disable the buttons, (spinner wont start).

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand from your comments for what purpose you trying to update the razor variable, but if you really wants to update your razor variable from 1 to 2 (from your question), then i would suggest to try like below

```
     @{
        int iconNumber = 1;
      }
```

then,

```
       <button type="submit" onclick="@(iconNumber++); alert('@iconNumber');"></button>
```

Hope it helps...But also note that iconNumber will increment on each click of button. So, I can help you if you show some more code